# Ansible fileinline not working with loop

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am trying to add or edit multiple lines in a file using `lineinfile` but not working. I am using below code with no luck Ref: [ansible: lineinfile for several lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334115/ansible-lineinfile-for-several-lines)

```
# vim /etc/ansible/playbook/test-play.yml 

- hosts: tst.wizvision.com
  tasks:
  - name: change of line
    lineinfile:
      dest: /root/test.txt
      regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
      line: "{{ item.line }}"
      backrefs: yes
      with_items:
      - { regexp: '^# line one', line: 'NEW LINE ONE' }
      - { regexp: '^# line two', line: 'NEW LINE TWO' }
```

**Ansible Error:**

```
# ansible-playbook test-2.yml
```

TASK [change of line] **********************************************************

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbook/test-2.yml': line 3, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n tasks:\n - name: change of line\n ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `with_items` is not indented correctly within the task.

`with_items` should be at the level of the module, not as a parameter to the module itself. In your case, you are passing `with_items` as a parameter to `lineinfile` module, and ansible is complaining that there is no parameter as `with_items` for `lineinfile` module.

Your task should look something like this -

```
tasks:
- name: change of line
  lineinfile:
    dest: /root/test.txt
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
    backrefs: yes
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '^# line one', line: 'NEW LINE ONE' }
    - { regexp: '^# line two', line: 'NEW LINE TWO' }
```