# Ansible: Canonical Way to Modify/Add Multiple Lines in a Config File

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have config files that come from a pre-existing deployment process. (Varying formats, but `java.properties` files comprise most of them, if it matters.)

I need to change (if the corresponding property exists), or add (if it doesn't) multiple properties in these files.

However, I have no control over the creation of the pre-existing files. They are created externally, and the variables I want to modify are scattered throughout the lines of the file.

It looks like `blockinfile` won't be useful here, since it seems to work on contiguous blocks of properties (is that correct?)

Does this mean I need to use multiple `lineinfile` declarations (or one using a `with_items` loop as per: [Ansible: `lineinfile` for several lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334115/)

Or is there a better more canonical way to deal with this.

For example, consider the following pre-existing file.

```ini
config.item_1=bear1
config.item_2=bear2
config.item_3=bear3
config.item_4=bear4
config.item_5=bear5
```

And I just want to modify `config.item1`, `config.item_3` to be (`dog1`, `cat1`). I also want to add `config.arbitrary.param.name=40` resulting in:

```ini
config.item_1=dog1
config.item_2=bear2
config.item_3=cat1
config.item_4=bear4
config.item_5=bear5
config.arbitrary.param.name=40
```

Comment: What is the exact problem with using `lineinfile` with a loop?

Comment: Nothing. The ask is just what is the canonical way to do this. If it is that, then that’s fine. I just wanted to make sure there wasn’t something else that most people tend to do for this use case.

Comment: The best is to be in complete control of your configuration file and use a template. If this is not possible and you just want to make sure some sporadic lines are present/absent, use lineinfile. If this is to control a full block of contiguous lines, use blockinfile.

Answer (score 0):

***Canonical Way to Modify/Add Multiple Lines in a Config File***

For a variable file **`config.yml`**

```yaml
item_1: dog1
item_2: bear2
item_3: cat1
item_4: bear4
item_5: bear5
arbitrary.param.name: 40
```

**1)** One option would be using the [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) and a template file **`java.properties.j2`**

```yaml
config.item_1={{ config.item_1 }}
config.item_2={{ config.item_2 }}
config.item_3={{ config.item_3 }}
config.item_4={{ config.item_4 }}
config.item_5={{ config.item_5 }}
config.arbitrary.param.name={{ config['arbitrary.param.name'] }}
```

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars: 
      file: config.yml
      name: config

  - template:
      src: java.properties.j2
      dest: java.properties
```

will result into an output of a **`java.properties`** file with content

```yaml
config.item_1=dog1
config.item_2=bear2
config.item_3=cat1
config.item_4=bear4
config.item_5=bear5
config.arbitrary.param.name=40
```

Please take note about [Ansible: Variables, bracket notation or dot notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544410/6771046) which is used in this example.

**2)** Another approach would be using the [`ini_file` module – Tweak settings in INI files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html)

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars:
      file: config.yml
      name: config

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ config | dict2items }}"

  - ini_file:
      path: java.properties
      option: "config.{{ item.key  }}"
      value: "{{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ config | dict2items }}"
```

will result into an output of a **`java.properties`** file with content

```yaml
config.item_1 = dog1
config.item_2 = bear2
config.item_3 = cat1
config.item_4 = bear4
config.item_5 = bear5
config.arbitrary.param.name = 40
```