# Ansible: Variables, bracket notation or dot notation?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am preparing for the RHCE exam. Can you help me with how to define the facts?

`ansible_facts['hostname']` or `ansible_hostname`

I feel the second one is faster, but I don't know, is it a problem if I use this format?

Comment: It shouldn't be about speed.

Answer (score 0):

According [referencing nested variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables) and [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) you can use just one or the other, or even `ansible_facts.hostname`.

Quoting from an older documentation version [What Makes A Valid Variable Name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html?highlight=ansible%20doc#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name)

> *However, if you choose to use dot notation be aware that some keys can cause problems because they collide with attributes and methods of python dictionaries. You should use bracket notation instead of dot notation if you use keys which start and end with two underscores (Those are reserved for special meanings in python) or are any of the known public attributes ...*

You may also prefer bracket notation when you are going to create dictionary keys dynamically or if the name include a dash (`-`).

**Further Documentation**

- [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

**Further Q&A**

- [What's the difference between `inventory_hostname` and `ansible_hostname`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908718/6771046)

and specifically for the RHCE exam

- [Why should I remove the `ansible_` prefix when refering to an ansible fact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859125/)

Comment: @KevinC, I interpret the documentation "_...if you use keys which start and end with two underscores (Those are reserved for special meanings in python) or are any of the known public attributes..._" that these are that one which start and end with two underscores and those are listed there [add, ... ,zfill](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html?highlight=ansible%20doc#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name).