# Ansible: yaml.representer.RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', AnsibleUndefined)

Tags: ansible

I am trying to access the dictionary which contains the alphanumeric item and its throwing error while traversing it.

Code:

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{ abccontent.json.nodes.item.jvm.mem.heap_used | to_nice_yaml }}"
  with_items:
    - RAV1MMn1TwKuxl229TbDFFQ
    - ZJeljFpTQXWl4dnlYDS4Ygw
    - _z9213e2uQJWT4rS3H_-QPw
    - KmNwadKddS_-rZZIK5TO3yQ
```

Error:

```yaml
TASK [get value : debug] ******************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: yaml.representer.RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', AnsibleUndefined)
failed: [abc.server.bame] (item= RAV1MMn1TwKuxl9pTbDFFQ) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: RAV1MMn1TwKuxl9pTbDFFQ
```

Is there a way to access those alphanumeric vaules in dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: What should the value like `RAV1MMn1TwKuxl9pTbDFFQ` represent ? 
If it is a string-literal, try [`with_list`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-list).

Comment: @hc_dev Its cluster node id. and I guess its alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance it looks like a syntax error. A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    TEST:
      RAV1MMn1TwKuxl229TbDFFQ:
        value: 1
      ZJeljFpTQXWl4dnlYDS4Ygw:
        value: 2
      _z9213e2uQJWT4rS3H_-QPw:
        value: 3
      KmNwadKddS_-rZZIK5TO3yQ:
        value: 4

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ TEST[item].value }}"
    loop:
      - RAV1MMn1TwKuxl229TbDFFQ
      - ZJeljFpTQXWl4dnlYDS4Ygw
      - _z9213e2uQJWT4rS3H_-QPw
      - KmNwadKddS_-rZZIK5TO3yQ
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=RAV1MMn1TwKuxl229TbDFFQ) =>
  msg: '1'
ok: [localhost] => (item=ZJeljFpTQXWl4dnlYDS4Ygw) =>
  msg: '2'
ok: [localhost] => (item=_z9213e2uQJWT4rS3H_-QPw) =>
  msg: '3'
ok: [localhost] => (item=KmNwadKddS_-rZZIK5TO3yQ) =>
  msg: '4'
```

In other words you can't use dot notation (`abccontent.json.nodes.item.jvm.mem.heap_used`) but bracket notation instead (`abccontent.json.nodes[item].jvm.mem.heap_used`).

**Some Documentation and Q&A**

- [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables)
- [Referencing nested variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables)
- [Ansible: Variables, bracket notation or dot notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544410/6771046)

---

**How to reproduce the error and narrow down the cause?**

By using in the minimal example playbook a line

```yaml
msg: "{{ TEST.item.value | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

one would get an error message of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', AnsibleUndefined)
failed: [localhost] (item=RAV1MMn1TwKuxl229TbDFFQ) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: RAV1MMn1TwKuxl229TbDFFQ
```

whereby after further simplification and reducing complexity by removing the filter

```yaml
msg: "{{ TEST.item.value }}"
```

one will see the root cause more clear

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'item'
```

Which is a true statement since not `abccontent.json.nodes.item` should become referenced but the content of `item`, a variable value.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Appreciate your help. It worked.