# How to get the value from key `datacenter` from a JSON output which is stored in an variable?

Tags: ansible, vmware

From this YAML output I need to get the `datacenter` value in a variable.

```yaml
changed: "false"
clusters: 
  ADC_CORE4: 
    hosts: 
    - name: "b125.abc.com"
      folder: "/ADC_3C/host/ADC_CORE4"
    enable_ha: "true"
    ha_failover_level: "2"
    resource_summary: 
      cpuCapacityMHz: "2183328"
      cpuUsedMHz: "71374"
    moid: "test"
    datacenter: "ADC_AI"
```

But the key `ADC_CORE4` is not stable and changes on every output I get when the cluster changes.

I like to get the `datacenter` value from this output and trying to use it in deployment of VM.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your example YAML data is the content of a variable `myvariable`, you can get the `datacenter` value like this:

```
(myvariable.clusters.values()|list).0.datacenter
```

The `values()` method returns a list of values; since there's only a single value, we just grab the first item in the list and then ask for the `datacenter` attribute.

For example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    myvariable:
      changed: "false"
      clusters: 
        ADC_CORE4: 
          hosts: 
          - name: "b125.abc.com"
            folder: "/ADC_3C/host/ADC_CORE4"
          enable_ha: "true"
          ha_failover_level: "2"
          resource_summary: 
            cpuCapacityMHz: "2183328"
            cpuUsedMHz: "71374"
          moid: "test"
          datacenter: "ADC_AI"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "datacenter: {{ (myvariable.clusters.values()|list).0.datacenter }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

An other approach than

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (cluster_info.clusters.values() | list | first).datacenter }}"
```

but [with bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544410/6771046) is

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters[(result.clusters.keys() | first)]['datacenter'] }}"
```

---

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    cluster_info:
      changed: "false"
      clusters:
        ADC_CORE4:
          hosts:
          - name: "b125.abc.com"
            folder: "/ADC_3C/host/ADC_CORE4"
          enable_ha: "true"
          ha_failover_level: "2"
          resource_summary:
            cpuCapacityMHz: "2183328"
            cpuUsedMHz: "71374"
          moid: "test"
          datacenter: "ADC_AI"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (cluster_info.clusters.values() | list | first).datacenter }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters[(result.clusters.keys() | first)]['datacenter'] }}"
```

will result for any `clusters.NAME` or `clusters['NAME']` into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: ADC_AI

TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: ADC_AI
```

---

Also possible and probably the more simple one is [Selecting JSON data: JSON queries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_selecting_json_data.html) as shown in your

**Duplicate Q&A**

- [How to get the `datacenter` value ... the name of `clusters` may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78105183/6771046)