# Get the value from the dict in JSON output stored in a variable

Tags: ansible, vmware

```
{
  "changed": false,
  "clusters": {
    "ADC_CORE4": {
      "enable_ha": true,
      "ha_failover_level": 2,
      "ha_vm_monitoring": "vmMonitoringDisabled",
      "datacenter": "ADC_AI"
    }
  }
}
```

this is the output and ADC_CORE4 this is the cluster value which keep on changing. how to get the datacenter value in an variable using set_facts in ansible.

#i stored the output as cluster_info. and tried to get the datacenter value using :

```
- name: get the datacenter value
    msg: "datacenter : {{ cluster_info.clusters.ADC_CORE4.datacenter }}"
```

but ADC_CORE4 is not constant value it keep on changing. so i cant use it in automation of deploying #the vm. so need help on how to get the datacenter value in an variable.

Answer (score 1):

Given the dictionary (equivalent in YAML for better readability):

```yaml
    cluster_info:
      changed: false
      clusters:
        ADC_CORE4:
          datacenter: ADC_AI
          enable_ha: true
          ha_failover_level: 2
          ha_vm_monitoring: vmMonitoringDisabled
```

Q: ***"Get the datacenter value in a variable using set_fact. The name of cluster(s) may vary."***

A: Use the filter *json_query*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        datacenter: "{{ cluster_info.clusters |
                        json_query('*.datacenter') }}"
```

gives a list because there might be more clusters

```yaml
  datacenter:
  - ADC_AI
```

In this particular case, take the first item

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        datacenter: "{{ cluster_info.clusters |
                        json_query('*.datacenter') |
                        first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  datacenter: ADC_AI
```

Comment: it works as expected @vladimir bota thanks for your hepl

Comment: It's worth to mention that `json_query` [relies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_selecting_json_data.html) on `jmespath` package that might not be installed on the controller.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev, right and in that case the answer on the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78106001/6771046) could be used.