# Ansible Playbook - Adding entries into /etc/hosts file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to read hosts from inventory file:

```
# PostgreSQL nodes
[all]
192.168.63.31 hostname=pgnode1
192.168.63.32 hostname=pgnode2
192.168.63.33 hostname=pgnode3
```

And add them to /etc/hosts file of all these nodes in the format below:

```
192.168.63.31 pgnode1
192.168.63.32 pgnode2
192.168.63.33 pgnode3
```

I have tried:

```
 - name: update host file
      lineinfile:
        state: present
        dest: /etc/hosts
        line: "{% for host in groups.all %} {{ host }} {{ hostvars\[host\]\['hostname'\] }} {% endfor %}"
```

I also tried `blockinfile` but it adds in this format not in separate lines:

```
192.168.63.32 pgnode2  192.168.63.33 pgnode3  192.168.63.31 pgnode1
```

I have tried whatever I could find but no luck. Please help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you escape the array notation in `hostvars\[host\]`? This is off course not the same as `hostvars[host]`

Comment: escape characters were just typo during copy & paste. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I also tried `blockinfile` ...*

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - blockinfile:
      state: present
      dest: etc_hosts
      content: |
        {% for host in groups.all %}
        {{ host }}
        {% endfor %}
```

will result into requested output.

> *... but it adds in this format not in separate lines*

This is because of the format of `line:`. It will also work with a format like

```yaml
  - lineinfile:
      state: present
      dest: etc_hosts
      line: |
        {% for host in groups.all %}
        {{ host }}
        {% endfor %}
```

However, the task will not be idempotent and add the lines several times.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: `lineinfile` for several lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334115/)

Comment: I guess I need to search better. Thank you very much for your help.